# Dart Paper-button onclick Event does not work

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to link a paper-button to an event but in the example below it does not seem  the event (add1) ist called at all.

Any Idea where is the problem?

```dart
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_button.html">

<polymer-element name="my-button">

    <template>
        <style>
            ..
        </style>

        <div>
            <div>
                <paper-button raised="" onclick="{{add1}}">Add 1</paper-button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>count is : {{count}}.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script type="application/dart" src="my_button.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

and the Dart file:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('my-button')
class MyButton extends PolymerElement {
  @observable int count = 0;
  MyButton.created() : super.created();

  void add1(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
    count++;
    print(count);
  }
}
```

Comment: sometimes converting to JS causes the linter to show such errors explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason it did not work was that I forgot the following statement:

```
import 'dart:html';
```

Answer (score 3):

You may replace *onclick="{{add1}}"* by *on-click="{{add1}}"*

Comment: It does not make any difference